# Ubuntu 22.04 ACPI BIOS Errors showing up but system boots just fine

Tags: 22.04, bios, acpi

I have been getting the following error message when booting up ubuntu:

```
[0.299654] ACPI BIOS Error (bug) Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.PB2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[0.299655] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[0.299714] ACPI BIOS Error (bug) Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.PB2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[0.299717] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
/dev/nvme0n1p4: clean, 214661/1438976 files, 2242756/5750016 blocks
```

You can also find an image of the error message [here][1] 
System/OS info:

- Ubuntu version: 22.04
- Kernel version: 5.15.0-57-generic
- Device: lenovo legion 7 slim laptop
- CPU: Ryzen 7 5800H
- BIOS Version: LENOVO HACN39WW

I've only tried running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and this message still persists. The system boots up fine and nothing seems blaringly wrong. I'm just worried this blows up later while i'm using the device.

**Note:** i'm running ubuntu alongside a windows 10 OS with a dual-boot configuration.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXH9h.jpg